# Что такое promise в Javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Что такое promise в Javascript и чем он отличается от [Deferred объектов](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/113073/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Речь о jQuery?

Если да — насколько я понимаю — разница между Deferred и Promise в том, что Promise позволяет только добавить коллбэки на события (`done`/`fail`/`always`), но не имеет возможности дожидаться вычисления или прерывать его (нет `resolve` и `reject`).

---

**Дополнено:**

Почитал что пишут в Интернетах. Мог что-то не так понять, но, надеюсь, понял все правильно.

Насколько я понял, вообще, термины deferred, promise, future и delay используются для обозначения, в широком смысле, одного и того же — некоего вычисления, результат которого только обещан, но еще неизвестен.

Разные авторы в разное время в своих публикациях вводили разные понятия, сходные, но отличающиеся в деталях. Например, в [arXiv:1008.1459v23](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1459) есть сравнение futures, как они определены у Baker и Hewitt [1977] с promises у [Liskov и Shrira [1988]](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=54016) следующим образом. Например, пишут, что futures могут быть использованы непосредственно, а чтобы получить результат promises должны быть сначала resolved. Это раз.

Также есть ситуация с реализациями. Кто как реализовал и кто как свою реализацию обозвал.

Скажем, бывает, когда результат доступен только для чтения (когда он будет), но на вычисление нельзя повлиять. Это, грубо, как различия между mutable и immutable объектами. И некоторые называют такое отдельным термином — например promise (vs deferred) в jQuery/Dojo, future (vs promise) в C++0x и т.д..

А бывает вообще по-другому. Например, в Ruby'овском gem'е [Promise](http://promise.rubyforge.org/) так: promise вычисляют когда результат понадобится и являются, в общем-то, несколько связанной с этим, но другой штукой — ленивым (отложенным) вычислением. Но название — promise — так вот назвал(и) автор(ы), хотя, скажем, ни о какой асинхронности (у Liskov и Shrira — возвращаясь к вышесказанному — когда они говорили о promises, речь шла об асинхронном RPC в распределенных системах), например, тут не идет — такого в принципе нет, просто откладываем вычисление до первого использования. А строгое асинхроное вычисление в отдельном потоке в том же gem'е называется future.

В общем, насколько я понимаю, никакой общепринятой терминологии нет, каждый называет по-своему (а когда хотят сослаться на конкретный смысл — делают отсылку к конкретной публикации/реализации), что не позволяет дать и общий ответ.

Comment: Вообще, интересно было узнать разницу концепций вообще. А реализации - они есть и в jQuery и в Dojo и в других фреймворках.

Comment: Покопался, почитал, дополнил.